# graph wide_long table ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Para stackflow

Hi everyone! This is my first post so I expect
to respect the rules and regulations of the
community when posting.

I write this because I am having real troubles in
generating a weighted percent stacked barchar
in ggplot2.

After several tries with survey data, I decided
that the best way to create the graph is to
construct a svyby dataframe as a previous stage.
The format of the table is somewhat strange but
I need that the prevalence of the different levels
of my key variables.

The resulting table looks something like this
(I will present it in a example database format
to make it easier to follow):

```
data <- data.frame( 
Year = c(2007,2011, 2015, 2019, 2007, 2011, 2015, 2019), 
Tenure = c("1","1","1","1", "2", "2","2","2"), 
Precarious_housing0 = c(0.93, 0.95, 0.96, 0.95, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.80), 
Precarious_housing1 = c(0.06, 0.04, 0.03, 0.04, 0.2, 0.19, 0.18, 0.16), 
Precarious_housing2 = c(0, 0.004, 0.001, 0, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.02), 
Precarious_housing3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0.02, 0.07, 0.04))
```

In this case, the variables Precarious_housingx represent the levels of precarious
housing (since the measure is a scale) that I want to graph. However, i have
not been able to do it, because of the strange format of the table.An illustrative
example of the graph that I would like to do is this:

[image]

How i can do it with ggplot2, and what changes I have to apply to the
database that I presented.

So much thanks

I have tried to do this through the survey data directly by applying the weights in ggplot2, but the magnitudes it gives me are wrong. I have also tried to do it by modifying the table but I have not been able to do it.

Comment: I generally use https://r-graph-gallery.com as a "shop by pictures" assortment of ggplot2 plots: they let you find the plot that you want to mimic, then they give you sample data and the code to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c("Year", "Tenure")) %>% 
  mutate(Year = factor(Year, levels = sort(unique(data$Year)), ordered = T)) %>% 
  group_by(Year, Tenure) %>% 
  mutate(sumval = sum(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(value = value/sumval) %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(Year, value, fill  = name), stat = "identity", position = "stack")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green"))+ #assign any colors you like
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Tenure))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To match the target image, the key steps are to pivot the last 3 columns into long format, ensure the labels are specified correctly, then theming the plot properly.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Precarious"), 
               names_pattern = "^.*(\\d)",
               names_to = "Precarious Housing Number",
               values_to = "Prevalence") %>%
  mutate(Tenure = paste(Tenure, "Year Tenure")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Year, Prevalence, fill = `Precarious Housing Number`)) +
  geom_col(position = position_fill(), width = 2) +
  facet_grid(.~Tenure) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2007, 2011, 2015, 2019), expand = c(0.1, 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ffd700", "#ffa604", "#ff7f00", "#cf6010")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "mm"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Allan! I have not been able to reply to your comment due to the recentness of the account but I would like to show my gratitude for your reply. Thanks to your code I was able to solve the problem. Thank you very much.